# How to let users share an Image from my application written with Qt for Android

Tags: android, qt

I'm developing an Android application using Qt. Now I'm going to let users share an image from my app. I tried to create new Intent:

```
package ir.qtips;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
public class ShareActivity extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity{
    private static ShareActivity instance;

        ShareActivity() {
            instance = this;
        }

        public void createInstagramIntent(){
            String type = "image/*";
            String captionText = "<< media caption >>";

            // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            // Set the MIME type
            share.setType(type);

            // Add the URI and the caption to the Intent.
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/a.jpg"));
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);

            // Broadcast the Intent.
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
        }

}
```

And then I tried to call `createInstagramIntent` from C++ :

```
#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
    QAndroidJniObject jni("ir/qtips/ShareActivity");
    jni.callMethod<void>("createInstagramIntent");
#endif
```

But It doesn't work.
In logs from app one line is more important than others I think:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Comment: What is the reason for not using QtMultimedia?

Comment: @lpapp Does it have an API for sharing photos?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a [Handler Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) from a thread that's hasn't called `Looper.prepare( )`. What you can do is you can create a `Handler` Thread like following using `Looper` Static Class

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Here is an [example project](https://github.com/deuteros76/qt-android-extras-text-to-speech) that has called Android Text to Speech Service. You can follow this code to solve your problem because Text To Speech should also be called the same way as `Share Intent`

Show/Hide keyboard example, It also needs to be called from the UI Thread. It may help you out.

```
{
    public void setSuspendSleep() {
        this.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
                {
                getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON );
                }        
        } );
    }

    public void setAllowSleep() {
        this.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                }
        } );
    }
}



------- and then in C++ ------

// getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
// getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
extern "C" void SuspendSleep( int bStopSleep )
{
    static int init;
    static jobject  WindowManager_LayoutParams_FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;

    // Attaches the current thread to the JVM. 
    jint lResult; 
    jint lFlags = 0; 

    JavaVM* lJavaVM = engine.app->activity->vm; 
    JNIEnv* lJNIEnv = engine.app->activity->env; 

    JavaVMAttachArgs lJavaVMAttachArgs; 
    lJavaVMAttachArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; 
    lJavaVMAttachArgs.name = "NativeThread"; 
    lJavaVMAttachArgs.group = NULL; 

    lResult=lJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&lJNIEnv, &lJavaVMAttachArgs);
    if (lResult == JNI_ERR) { 
        return; 
    } 

    // Retrieves NativeActivity. 
    jobject lNativeActivity = engine.app->activity->clazz; 
    jclass ClassNativeActivity = lJNIEnv->GetObjectClass(lNativeActivity);

    if( bStopSleep )
    {
        jmethodID MethodSetFlags = lJNIEnv->GetMethodID(      ClassNativeActivity, "setSuspendSleep", "()V");
        if( MethodSetFlags )
            lJNIEnv->CallVoidMethod( lNativeActivity,  MethodSetFlags );
    }
    else
    {
        jmethodID MethodSetFlags = lJNIEnv->GetMethodID(      ClassNativeActivity, "setAllowSleep", "()V");
        if( MethodSetFlags )
            lJNIEnv->CallVoidMethod( lNativeActivity,  MethodSetFlags );
    }



    // Finished with the JVM. 
    lJavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
}
```